# Monkey Patch Guard Cucumber Notification Formatter not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, guard, monkeypatching

I want to make a simple change to the Guard Cucumber Notification Formatter to pass a priority, a bit like Guard Rspec does, so that growl styling can be improved.  Small thing really.

I have tried this as a monkey patch in an initializer file but it won't work.  I've tried all kinds of things but for whatever reason I cannot get it to recognize my monkey-patch when running the tests.  No change I make in the patch seems to make a difference.  I've tried all kinds of variants on the namespacing in case I'm making an error there - and I think that's most likely.  Here's what I'm trying to apply:

```
initializers/guard_cucumber_patch.rb

require 'guard'
require 'guard/notifier'
require 'cucumber/formatter/console'
require 'cucumber/formatter/io'

module Guard
  class Cucumber
    class NotificationFormatter
      def step_name(keyword, step_match, status, source_indent, background, file_colon_line)
        if [:failed, :pending, :undefined].index(status)
          @rerun = true
          step_name = step_match.format_args(lambda { |param| "*#{ param }*" })

          ::Guard::Notifier.notify(step_name,
            :title => @feature_name,
            :image => icon_for(status),
            :priority => priority(icon_for(status)))
        end
      end

      # Just stolen from the guard/rspec/formatter code
      def priority(image)
        { :failed => 2,
          :pending => -1,
          :success => -2
        }[image]
      end

    end
  end
end
```

The original guard/cucumber/notification_formatter.rb file is as follows:

```
require 'guard'
require 'guard/notifier'
require 'cucumber/formatter/console'
require 'cucumber/formatter/io'

module Guard
  class Cucumber

    # The notification formatter is a Cucumber formatter that Guard::Cucumber
    # passes to the Cucumber binary. It writes the `rerun.txt` file with the failed features
    # an creates system notifications.
    #
    # @see https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Custom-Formatters
    #
    class NotificationFormatter
      include ::Cucumber::Formatter::Console

      attr_reader :step_mother

      # Initialize the formatter.
      #
      # @param [Cucumber::Runtime] step_mother the step mother
      # @param [String, IO] path_or_io the path or IO to the feature file
      # @param [Hash] options the options
      #
      def initialize(step_mother, path_or_io, options)
        @options = options
        @file_names = []
        @step_mother = step_mother
      end

      # Notification after all features have completed.
      #
      # @param [Array[Cucumber::Ast::Feature]] features the ran features
      #
      def after_features(features)
        notify_summary
        write_rerun_features if !@file_names.empty?
      end

      # Before a feature gets run.
      #
      # @param [Cucumber::Ast::FeatureElement] feature_element
      #
      def before_feature_element(feature_element)
        @rerun = false
        @feature_name = feature_element.name
      end

      # After a feature gets run.
      #
      # @param [Cucumber::Ast::FeatureElement] feature_element
      #
      def after_feature_element(feature_element)
        if @rerun
          @file_names << feature_element.file_colon_line
          @rerun = false
        end
      end

      # Gets called when a step is done.
      #
      # @param [String] keyword the keyword
      # @param [Cucumber::StepMatch] step_match the step match
      # @param [Symbol] status the status of the step
      # @param [Integer] source_indent the source indentation
      # @param [Cucumber::Ast::Background] background the feature background
      # @param [String] file name and line number describing where the step is used
      #
      def step_name(keyword, step_match, status, source_indent, background, file_colon_line)
        if [:failed, :pending, :undefined].index(status)
          @rerun = true
          step_name = step_match.format_args(lambda { |param| "*#{ param }*" })

          ::Guard::Notifier.notify step_name, :title => @feature_name, :image => icon_for(status)
        end
      end

      private

      # Notify the user with a system notification about the
      # result of the feature tests.
      #
      def notify_summary
        icon, messages = nil, []

        [:failed, :skipped, :undefined, :pending, :passed].reverse.each do |status|
          if step_mother.steps(status).any?
            step_icon = icon_for(status)
            icon = step_icon if step_icon
            messages << dump_count(step_mother.steps(status).length, 'step', status.to_s)
          end
        end

        ::Guard::Notifier.notify messages.reverse.join(', '), :title => 'Cucumber Results', :image => icon
      end

      # Writes the `rerun.txt` file containing all failed features.
      #
      def write_rerun_features
        File.open('rerun.txt', 'w') do |f|
          f.puts @file_names.join(' ')
        end
      end

      # Gives the icon name to use for the status.
      #
      # @param [Symbol] status the cucumber status
      # @return [Symbol] the Guard notification symbol
      #
      def icon_for(status)
        case status
          when :passed
            :success
          when :pending, :undefined, :skipped
            :pending
          when :failed
            :failed
          else
            nil
        end
      end

    end
  end
end
```

EDIT: I am using jruby-head if that makes a difference to monkey business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guard::Cucumber makes a [system](https://github.com/netzpirat/guard-cucumber/blob/master/lib/guard/cucumber/runner.rb#L26) call to start Cucumber in a subshell and your monkey patch is not loaded in that environment. You need to tell Cucumber to require your patch on start like the notification formatter is [required](https://github.com/netzpirat/guard-cucumber/blob/master/lib/guard/cucumber/runner.rb#L51).

I'm not actively developing Guard::Cucumber at the moment because I have no project with Cucumber, but I still do maintain it and I'll happily merge that improvement if you make a pull request. I think your improvement would be useful for other users as well.

Comment: Ah.  That makes sense now you point it out.  Thanks.  I've never submitted any change to a project before but I'll try to do that and hopefully won't make a complete mess of it.  I'll read up about it so I do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

try to put this file in `spec/support` dir (create if not exists)

this dir contents are usually included in `spec/spec_helper.rb` just before running any tests

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. No joy. I have the dir contenst included and when adding it to that directory it makes no difference :-/  Your suggestion prompted me to also try the features/support directory but no joy there either.  I am guessing it's something  to do with the nested namespacing that I'm getting wrong.  I have made a couple of obvious code changes so I can be sure of whether it's working or not - changed title to always be "HELLO THIS IS WORKING" for example.  Definitely not working.

Comment: okay then try to be sure that you are patching right classes, I mean if they are really executed? As a last resort you can put some `raise`'s in your **original** `guard/cucumber/notification_formatter.rb` (that's it, a system one, usually sitting in `/usr`, or, maybe, in `~/.rvm/gems/whatever` you got the idea)